# when use kendoCircularGauge in kendo grid column shrinking, when do kendo resize it become right position

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo UI jquery, when use kendoCircularGauge in kendo grid column shrinking, when do kendo resize it become right position. I am using panel content when click the panel am loading the grid with the gauge.
i want when click the panel it should be resize without resize in js.
[image]

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, or even better, reproduce the issue in a Kendo DOJO/CodePen/jsFiddle/etc. so we can better understand what you are asking.